# Jquery: Hover function

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I need to change css on hover different class. Following is the code

```
<li class="dropdown whitedrop" id="dropdown" style="width: 229px;">
    <div class="greenStripe"></div> <a data-target="#" style="cursor: Default;margin-left: 50px;width: 180px;" class="fnd-nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown"><span id="loggedon_lable">Logged on:</span>
        <span id="loggedon_user"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul id="whitedropdown-menu" class="whitedropdown-menu fnd-tweak-dropdown" style="">
        <li class="borderli disabledMenu"> <a tabindex="-1" style="cursor: default">My Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="borderli disabledMenu"> <a tabindex="-1" style="cursor: default">Settings</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

On hovering, 'whitedropdown-menu' i need to change background of 'greenStripe'.

I tried,

```
.whitedropdown-menu:hover .greenStripe {
    background:#029f1c;
}
```

It didn't work actually.But i need it in jquery not css.
For that i tried,

```
$(".whitedropdown-menu").hover(function () {
    $(".greenStripe").css('background', '#029f1c');
});
```

But once i hover, background changes and it's not getting reverted when i am not hovering.

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: you have to tell it to remove the styles manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".whitedropdown-menu").hover(function(){
     // Function called when hover
     // Go from background1 to background2

}, function() {
   // Function called when hover end
   // Go from background2 to background1
});
```

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 0):

Try mouseout code:

```
$( ".whitedropdown-menu" ).mouseout(function() {
     $(".greenStripe").css('background','#029f1c'); //change this color to the color you want
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
$(".whitedropdown-menu").mouseout(function() {
   $(".greenStripe").css('background','#029f1c');
});
```

You have to add one more jquery event to handle this. OnMouseOut you have to changed the background again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the styles once the mouse cursor leaves your container:

```js
$('.whitedropdown-menu').mouseout(function() {
    $('.greenStripe').css('background','none'); //replace the none with the initial background color
});
```